# Dynamics 365 subject tree not updating case dropdown

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

When I update subject tree with new subjects or change subjects, I do not see it reflected in the case subject dropdown. I can go back into the subject tree and I see my changes are there and saved.

How do I get my Subject tree changes to show in the case subject dropdown?

Comment: Did you set the featuremask while creating subject?

Comment: No, i am not sure what that is. I changed the Subject tree from <settings><service management><subject>. Where do i find featuremask?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you created via code. Subject created in UI tree should reflect in case until unless it messed up in DB. Do you want to remove & re-add it..?

Comment: i have added and deleted subject items and none are showing in the case form dropdown, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any custom subject attribute, looking at the native subject tree relation in incident.

I will start digging the `subject` in XrmToolbox - FetchXml Builder for any discrepancy in data like `featuremask` (need to be 1). We cannot check this in Adv.Find as Subject is not searchable, also if you are in on-premise do the SQL way.

```
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="subject" >
    <attribute name="description" />
    <attribute name="featuremask" />
    <attribute name="subjectid" />
    <attribute name="versionnumber" />
    <attribute name="modifiedby" />
    <attribute name="createdby" />
    <attribute name="modifiedon" />
    <attribute name="title" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="organizationid" />
    <attribute name="parentsubject" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, our subject tree did update after i went back to check after a few days.  We are not on-premise. Do you know why it tool so long to update the case subject dropdown?

Comment: @MorganHayes not sure why you experience a delay.. you can check with MS by raising a ticket..

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue. I added a couple of new subjects and they weren't appearing on the Case form. To resolve this I went to: Settings > Customizations > Customize the System. I then published all customizations and the new subjects started appearing on the Case form.